# Need to make this expression shorter in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to make my code more compact. I have the following code:

```
params[:investor][:profit] = params[:investor][:profit].nil? ? nil : params[:investor][:profit].gsub(/\D/, '')
```

Basically what it does - it formats profit value from params to contain only digits, and if it was nil - just keep it nil...Is there any way to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:investor][:profit] &&= params[:investor][:profit].gsub(/\D/, '')
```

If the value of `params[:investor][:profit]` is nil, this will evaluate to `nil && ...`. Since nil is false, it will stay at nil, otherwise do the `gsub`.

I think it is heads up with the `try` solution mentioned in another solution. Choosing one over the other comes down to personal taste. I like the `&&=` solution because it's ruby instead of a rails convenience method and you do not need to "encrypt" what you really want to do in the try method's parameters.

Comment: i like your solution very much - i did not know that there is an opposite of ||=, but now thanks to you i will be using &&= :) Thank you

Comment: Glad you like the solution. Would be great if you could mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could tighten it down a little bit like so:

```
params[:investor][:profit].gsub!(/\D/, '') unless params[:investor][:profit].nil?
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [#try method from active_support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
params[:investor][:profit].try(:gsub!, /\D/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

um

```
p = params[:investor][:profit]
p = p.nil? ? nil : p.gsub(/\D/,'')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i actually need to update params array so i can use it later...

Answer (score 1):

```
params[:investor][:profit].gsub!(/\D/, '') if params[:investor][:profit]
```

or what I almost always use:

```
params[:investor][:profit].gsub!(/\D/, '') rescue nil
```

Comment: The second variant is discouraged as it swallows *any* error (including ones not  intended to be swallowed) and only poorly communicates the real intend of the code.

Comment: @holger - Yes but it's just what you want when you're mainly concerned with the script completing.

Answer (score 0):

```
prof = params[:investor][:profit]
prof.gsub!(/\D/,'') if prof
```